# How do I configure Hazelcast read-through Map when only part of the nodes are able to populate the Map data?

Tags: hazelcast

Let's say I have two types of Hazelcast nodes running on cluster:

- *"Leader"* nodes – these are able to load and populate Hazelcast map `M`. Leaders will also update values in `M` from time to time (based on external resource).
- *"Follower"* nodes – these will need to read from `M`

My intent is for *Follower* nodes to trigger loading missing elements into `M` (loading thus needs to be done on *Leader* side) .

Roughly, the steps made to get an element from map could look like this:

```
IMap m = hazelcastInstance.getMap("M");
if (!m.containsKey(k)) {  
    if (iAmLeader()) { 
        Object fresh = loadByKey(k); // loading from external resource 
        return m.put(k, fresh);
    } else {
        makeSomeLeaderPopulateValueForKey(k);
    }
 }
 return m.get(k);
```

What approach could you suggest?

---

#### Notes

1. I want *Followers* to act as nodes, not just clients, because there are going to be far more Follower instances than Leaders and I would like them to participate in load distribution.
2. I could just build another level of service, that would run only on *Leader* nodes and provide interface to populate map with requested keys. But that would mean adding extra layer of communication and configuration, and I was hoping that the kind of requirements stated above could be solved within single Hazelcast cluster.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just looking for cluster members (leaders) and clients (followers)? Tbh not sure I understood exactly what you try to achieve.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `iAmLeader()` ? How do you determine which is leader and which is follower?

Comment: @noctarius I added some notes on that. Thanks for helping me define scope of the problem more clearly.

Comment: @PeterandtheWolf maybe have a look for lite member (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#enabling-lite-members) work for your usecase. In this case the member wouldn't store any data too but could be used for operation execution.

Comment: I understand what he's asking and I'm looking for exactly the same thing. Basically he wants a cache. Where (for simplicity) the cache has level 0 and 1. Level 1 is in the cache for a client (follower) to access and level 0 is not in the cache (maybe in a file, database, etc). If a client requests data from the cache that is in level 0 and thus has to be promoted to level 1, then it is only the leader's responsibility to figure out how that occurs. That means the leader needs to be notified of what data needs to be promoted and it would be invisible to a client (follower).

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found an answer in the form of [MapLoader](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/2.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapLoader.html) (EDIT since originally posting, I have confirmed this is indeed the way to do this).

```
final Config config = new Config();
config.getMapConfig("MY_MAP_NAME").setMapStoreConfig(
        new MapStoreConfig().setImplementation(new MapLoader<KeyType, ValueType>(){
                @Override
                public ValueType load(final KeyType key) {
                    //when a client asks for data for corresponding key of type
                    //KeyType that isn't already loaded
                    //this function will be invoked and give you a chance
                    //to load it and return it
                    ValueType rv = ...;
                    return rv;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<KeyType, ValueType> loadAll(
                        final Collection<KeyType> keys) {
                    //Similar to MapLoader#load(KeyType), except this is
                    //a batched version of it for performance gains.
                    //this gets called on first access to the cache,
                    //where MapLoader#loadAllKeys() is called to get
                    //the keys parameter for this funcion
                    Map<KeyType, ValueType> rv = new HashMap<>();
                    keys.foreach((key)->{
                        rv.put(key, /*figure out what key means*/);
                    });
                    return rv;
                }

                @Override
                public Set<KeyType> loadAllKeys() {
                    //Prepopulate all the keys. My understanding is that
                    //this is an initialization step, to give you a chance
                    //to load data on startup so an initial set of datas
                    //will be available to anyone using the cache. Any keys
                    //returned here are sent to MapLoader#loadAll(Collection)
                    Set<KeyType> rv = new HashSet<>();
                    //figure out what keys need to be in the return value
                    //to load a key into cache at first access to this map,
                    //named "MY_MAP_NAME" in this example
                    return rv;
                }
        }));
config.getGroupConfig().setName("MY_INSTANCE_NAME").setPassword("my_password");
final HazelcastInstance hazelcast = Hazelcast
        .getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(config);
```